# How to view an HTML file in the browser with Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, preview

How can I view my HTML code in a browser with the new Microsoft Visual Studio Code?

With Notepad++ you have the option to Run in a browser. How can I do the same thing with Visual Studio Code?

Comment: also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47519768/how-do-i-set-the-default-browser-as-chrome-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: Microsoft released the even easier to setup "Live Preview" extension. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69210917/2713729

Answer (score 262, accepted):

For Windows - Open your Default Browser - Tested on VS Code v 1.1.0

Answer to both opening a specific file (name is hard-coded) OR opening ANY other file.

**Steps:**

1. Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> (or <kbd>F1</kbd>) to open the Command Palette.
2. Type in `Tasks: Configure Task` or on older versions `Configure Task Runner`. Selecting it will open the **tasks.json** file. Delete the script displayed and replace it by the following:

   ```
   {
       "version": "0.1.0",
       "command": "explorer",    
       "windows": {
           "command": "explorer.exe"
       },
       "args": ["test.html"]
   }
   ```

   Remember to change the "args" section of the tasks.json file to the name of your file. This will always open that specific file when you hit F5.

   You may also set the this to open whichever file you have open at the time by using `["${file}"]` as the value for "args". Note that the `$` goes outside the `{...}`, so `["{$file}"]` is incorrect.
3. Save the file.
4. Switch back to your html file (in this example it's "text.html"), and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> to view your page in your Web Browser.

[image]

Comment: awesome it worked! Just out of curiosity: why explorer exe. It opens the page in Chrome afterall. How can I open it in Internet explorer? And I replaced the "test.html" with the name of my html page. I hope thats the right way to do. Again thnaks!

Comment: explorer.exe will launch the default Web browser. If you want to open the page in Internet explorer, you just need to make it default: IE > Internet Options > Programs > Make default. @Orphydian

Comment: You can even use variables if you have more than one HTML file. You can do: "args": ["{$file}"] to pass the current open file. See also https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/tasks#_variables-in-tasksjson

Comment: I have another HTML file named "second_page.html". How should be that "args"line in this case? Do I need to keep the previous "args" line too?

Comment: How do I do it in Mac? There are no exe files. I would like to open the webpage in chrome on Mac

Comment: If someone is getting "No task runner configured", closing and re-opening Visual Studio Code worked for me!

Comment: do you "change" parameters in task runner? or ADD your code to task runner? thx

Comment: just getting "Failed to launch external program chrome {$file}.
spawn chrome ENOENT"

Comment: This process worked for me, but why do we have to hard-code "test.html" into this process?  can we not preview any .html file in this directory through by simply opening it up and pressing ctrl+shift+b? I have multiple html files I would like to preview at any given time in my folder...

Comment: To Configure Task in a new folder:

Select the Tasks: Configure Task Runner command and you will see a list of task runner templates. Select **Others** to create a task which runs an external command.   .   .   .

You should now see a **tasks.json file in your workspace .vscode folder** with the following content:   .   .  .

by  https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks

Comment: Why is the shortcut cmd + shift + b? I want to add similar shortcuts for firefox and safari but I'm not clear how I would be able to configure the keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: @MJGwater in 1.10 you can assign your shortcut by editing `keybindings.json` and inserting there entry like `{
    "key": "<shortcut>",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args":"<task name>"
}`, By default there are shortcuts for build('cmd+shift+b') and test('cmd+shift+t') tasks.

Comment: Configure Task Runner is no longer present in VSC 1.24.0 - Control-Shift-P returns no results for that string.

Comment: Configure Task Runner has changed to "Tasks: Configure Task"

Comment: Pressing f5 on an unsaved HTML file send an `'${file}' can not be resolved. Please open an editor.[Open launch.json] `

Comment: 1.) Right-click 2.) Click "View In Browser". Oh wait, that was just a dream.

Comment: @Rodney https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=techer.open-in-browser

Comment: I cannot find the default keybindings.

Comment: With `F1` `tasks: configure task` I get `select a task to configure` with . Which one to take? Maybe `create task from template`.

Comment: Playing with `tasks.json` is no fun, [be told](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55120139/1705829) and keep your beloved at home.

Comment: Does that work when the files sit on a remote server ?

Answer (score 250):

VS Code has a [Live Server Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) that supports one click launch from status bar.

Some of the features:

- One Click Launch from Status Bar
- Live Reload
- Support for Chrome Debugging Attachment

[image]

Comment: This extension also has a web add-on to provide automatic reload functionality to dynamic pages.

Comment: @M.Sundstrom can you give me the name/link of that add-on please?

Comment: Still very useful, and especially completely configuration free!

Comment: This is not recommended for complex pages maybe good for new coders

Comment: Do you mean the browser extension or the vs code extension @YasserAkram?

Comment: Well, both maybe. I never had a good experience with it. Even the Atom one. Currently I'm much better fine with Brackets.IO for basic coding and templating @M.Sundstrom

Comment: tested on win 7, works like a charm. basically creates a local server.

Comment: but it seems you can't preview the unsaved active file right? (Running it, doesn't preview the html, but shows on the browser the folder hierarchy)

Comment: What about PHP extension?

Comment: does it show changes in Javascript on save live in browser?

Comment: @JinSnow feature is on [beta](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server-plus-plus)

Comment: thank you so much , this is so much helpful to running html only , auto reload just only click go live :)

Answer (score 83):

@InvisibleDev - to get this working on a mac trying using this:

```json
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "Chrome",
    "osx": {
        "command": "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
    },
    "args": [
        "${file}"
    ]
}
```

If you have chrome already open, it will launch your html file in a new tab.

Answer (score 76):

1. Open Extensions Sidebar (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>)
2. Search for [*open in browser*](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=techer.open-in-browser) and install it

   [image: Ext > Open in Browser]
3. Right click on your html file, and select "Open in Browser" (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>)

   [image: Context Menu> Open in Browser]

Comment: Works great in Windows.

Comment: Works for mac too. You just need to use `Cmd` + `Shift` + `X` and then the rest is the same.

Comment: Doesn't work when using a remote SSH environment.

Comment: @ProfessorKaos64 any solution in remote SSH

Comment: Simple and sufficient solution . I'm using it to quickly check static files in the browser (e.g. check test coverage report, or similar).

Answer (score 32):

If you would like to have live reload you can use gulp-webserver, which will watch for your file changes and reload page, this way you don't have to press F5 every time on your page:

Here is how to do it:

- Open command prompt (cmd) and type

  npm install --save-dev gulp-webserver
- Enter **Ctrl+Shift+P** in VS Code and type **Configure Task Runner**. Select it and press enter. It will open tasks.json file for you. Remove everything from it end enter just following code

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "gulp",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [
        "--no-color"
    ],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "webserver",
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "showOutput": "always"
        }
    ]
}
```

- In the root directory of your project add gulpfile.js and enter following code:

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    webserver = require('gulp-webserver');

gulp.task('webserver', function () {
    gulp.src('app')
        .pipe(webserver({
            livereload: true,
            open: true
        }));
});
```

- Now in VS Code enter **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type "Run Task" when you enter it you will see your task "webserver" selected and press enter.

Your webserver now will open your page in your default browser. Now any changes that you will do to your HTML or CSS pages will be automatically reloaded.

Here is an information on how to configure ['gulp-webserver'](https://github.com/schickling/gulp-webserver) for instance port, and what page to load, ...

You can also run your task just by entering **Ctrl+P** and type **task webserver**

Comment: I had to run `npm install -g gulp`, `npm install -g gulp-webserver` and add a NODE_PATH environment variable that points to my AppData\npm\node_modules. Then I was able to run the webserver task, however I get a 404 when the browser starts. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Never mind, just had to change the 'app' in your example to '.' (so it serves from the current directory).

Comment: One comment to the answer: If you want to run an html file in yor browser, which will automatic reload on changes, your gulpfile.js should look like this, with a '.' instead of the 'app'. Code =                                            var gulp = require('gulp'),
    webserver = require('gulp-webserver');

gulp.task('webserver', function () {
    gulp.src('.')
        .pipe(webserver({
            fallback: 'index.html',
            livereload: true,
            open: true
        }));
});

Comment: This is awesome.  Thanks for explaining this as a valuable option.  I also had apply a little bit of both Krill and Friis's answers to get this working.  But it does!

Comment: I was getting "Cannot GET /" because I copypasted gulpfile.js without configuring the line `gulp.src('app')` so that it actually pointed to my source (which wasn't `/app` but '.'). Works perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

You can now install an extension [View In Browser](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qinjia.view-in-browser). I tested it on windows with chrome and it is working.

vscode version: 1.10.2

[image]

Comment: That extension gets horrible reviews.

Comment: This doesn't automatically refresh the browser and this is not what OP is looking for

Answer (score 25):

[image: VS Code Settings Gear wheel icon]

Click on this **Left-Bottom** Manage Icon. Click **Extensions** or Short Cut `Ctrl+Shift+X`

Then Search in Extension with this key sentence **Open In Default Browser**. You will find [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=peakchen90.open-html-in-browser) Extension. It is better to me.

Now right click on the `html` file and you will see **Open in Default Browser** or Short Cut `Ctrl+1` to see the `html` file in browser.

Comment: The shortcut `ctrl+1` overwrites the default `ctrl+1` intelligently, opening a browser when in `html` in explorer, otherwise it sets the cursor in the current `editor`.

Comment: @Mr. Perfectionist : well explained

Answer (score 25):

There's now an official extension from the VS Code team called [Live Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.live-server)

Quick setup:

1. Install the extension from Microsoft.
2. Open a HTML file **from the workspace**, files outside current workspace don't work.
3. Run command **Live Preview: Show Preview (External Browser)** (`livePreview.start.externalPreview.atFile`)

There's also a command for launching it in the internal browser: **Live Preview: Show Preview (Internal Browser)** (`livePreview.start.internalPreview.atFile`).

You might also need to change the default port from the extension settings in case it's already in use on your system.

Answer (score 22):

Here is a 2.0.0 version for the current document in Chrome w/ keyboard shortcut:

`tasks.json`

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Chrome",
            "type": "process",
            "command": "chrome.exe",
            "windows": {
                "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
            },
            "args": [
                "${file}"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

`keybindings.json` :

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+g",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "Chrome"
}
```

For running on a webserver:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer

Answer (score 20):

In linux, you can use the [`xdg-open`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15354/how-to-open-file-with-default-application-from-command-line#15356) command to open the file with the default browser:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "linux": {
        "command": "xdg-open"
    },
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "never",
    "args": ["${file}"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm a Linux user and was feeling lost. I'd like to add that one needs to press `Ctrl + Shift + b` to launch it in the browser. For me, the mnemonic was "b = browser". :-)

Comment: It works but seems deprecated, if you have an updated version, thank you

Comment: Can you leave the version entry here in the tasks.json?

Answer (score 15):

I am just re-posting the steps I used from `msdn` blog. It may help the community.

This will help you to
setup a local web server known as [lite-server](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server) with `VS Code`, and also guides you to host your static `html` files in `localhost` and `debug` your `Javascript` code.

**1. Install Node.js**

If not already installed, get it [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node)

It comes with npm (the package manager for acquiring and managing your development libraries)

**2. Create a new folder for your project**

Somewhere in your drive, create a new folder for your web app.

**3. Add a package.json file to the project folder**

Then copy/paste the following text:

```
{
   "name": "Demo",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "demo project.",
   "scripts": {
     "lite": "lite-server --port 10001",
     "start": "npm run lite"
   },
   "author": "",
   "license": "ISC",
   "devDependencies": {
     "lite-server": "^2.5.4"
   }
}
```

**4. Install the web server**

In a terminal window (command prompt in Windows) opened on your project folder, run this command:

```
npm install
```

This will install lite-server (defined in package.json), a static server that loads index.html in your default browser and auto refreshes it when application files change.

**5. Start the local web server!**

(Assuming you have an index.html file in your project folder).

In the same terminal window (command prompt in Windows) run this command:

```
npm start
```

Wait a second and index.html is loaded and displayed in your default browser served by your local web server!

lite-server is watching your files and refreshes the page as soon as you make changes to any html, js or css files.

And if you have VS Code configured to auto save (menu File / Auto Save), you see changes in the browser as you type!

**Notes:**

- Do not close the command line prompt until you’re done coding in your
  app for the day
- It opens on http://localhost:10001 but you can change the port by
  editing the package.json file.

That’s it. Now before any coding session just type npm start and you are good to go!

*Originally posted [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2016/01/24/visual-studio-code-and-local-web-server/) in `msdn` blog.
Credits goes to Author : `@Laurent Duveau`*

Answer (score 6):

If you're just on Mac this `tasks.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "open",
    "args": ["${file}"],
}
```

...is all you need to open the current file in Safari, assuming its extension is ".html".

Create `tasks.json` as described above and invoke it with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>.

If you want it to open in Chrome then:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "open",
    "args": ["-a", "Chrome.app", "${file}"],
}
```

This will do what you want, as in opening in a new tab if the app is already open.

Answer (score 4):

**For Mac - Opens in Chrome - Tested on VS Code v 1.9.0**

1. Use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> to open the Command Palette.

[image]

2. Type in Configure Task Runner, the first time you do this, VS Code will give you the scroll down menu, if it does select "Other."  If you have done this before, VS Code will just send you directly to tasks.json.
3. Once in the tasks.json file. Delete the script displayed and replace it by the following:

> ```
> {
>     "version": "0.1.0",
>     "command": "Chrome",
>     "osx": {
>         "command": "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
>     },
>     "args": ["${file}"]
> }
> ```

4. Switch back to your html file and press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> to view your page in Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

One click solution simply install [open-in-browser](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=techer.open-in-browser) Extensions from the Visual Studio marketplace.

Answer (score 2):

`CTRL+SHIFT+P` will bring up the command palette.
Depending on what you're running of course. Example in an ASP.net app you can type in:
`>kestrel` and then open up your web browser and type in `localhost:(your port here)`.

If you type in `>` it will show you the *show and run commands*

Or in your case with HTML, I think `F5` after opening the command palette should open the debugger.

Source: [link](https://youtu.be/lEI9mxYpcS8)

Comment: I got this opening http://content.screencast.com/users/Orphydian/folders/3ds%20max/media/000527e5-f14f-477a-9938-b585d47e6449/05.05.2015-00.01.png

Answer (score 2):

Openning files in Opera browser (on Windows 64 bits). Just add this lines:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "opera",
"windows": {
    "command": "///Program Files (x86)/Opera/launcher.exe"
},
"args": ["${file}"] }
```

Pay attention to the path format on ***"command":*** line. Don't use the "C:\path_to_exe\runme.exe" format.

To run this task, open the html file you want to view, press F1, type **task opera** and press enter

Answer (score 2):

my runner script looks like :

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",

    "command": "explorer",

    "windows": {
        "command": "explorer.exe"
    },

    "args": ["{$file}"]
}
```

and it's just open my explorer when I press ctrl shift b in my index.html file

Answer (score 2):

here is how you can run it in multiple browsers for windows

```
{
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "command": "cmd",
 "args": ["/C"],
 "isShellCommand": true,
 "showOutput": "always",
 "suppressTaskName": true,
 "tasks": [
     {   
         "taskName": "Chrome",
         "args": ["start chrome -incognito \"${file}\""]
     },
     {   
         "taskName": "Firefox",
         "args": ["start firefox -private-window \"${file}\""]
     },
     {   
         "taskName": "Edge",
         "args": ["${file}"]
     }   
    ]
}
```

notice that I didn't type anything in args for edge because Edge is my default browser just gave it the name of the file.

EDIT: also you don't need -incognito nor -private-window...it's just me I like to view it in a private window

Comment: I was copying only the `tasks` part. the `"args":["/C"]` is what makes this work. Out of curiosity, what does this do?

Answer (score 1):

Yet another extension for previewing HTML files, called [Live Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.live-server). Couple reasons why I like it over the "Live Server" linked in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48721885/1212547).

- no need to start server, preview icon is integrated to into VS code (same as for mark down preview)
- preview is opened within the VS code in split view (although option to open in browser is available)
- developed by Microsoft (the same company developing VS code)
- currently the "Live Preview" is in "Preview", just prefect :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the version 2.0.0 for Mac OSx:

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "echo",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "echo Hello"
    },
    {
      "label":"chrome",
      "type":"process",
      "command":"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome",
      "args": [
        "${file}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Mac, set your tasks.json (in the .vscode folder) file contents to the following and use SHFT+COMMAND+B to open.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Chrome Preview",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "open -a /Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app test.html",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

VSCode Task - Open by App bundle identifier (macOS only).

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Open In: Firefox DE",
      "type": "process",
      "command": "open",
      "args": ["-b", "org.mozilla.firefoxdeveloperedition", "${file}"],
      "group": "build",
      "problemMatcher": [],
      "presentation": {
        "panel": "shared",
        "focus": false,
        "clear": true,
        "reveal": "never",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following worked in version 1.53.2 on windows 10 ->

- choose run active file in terminal menu
- It executed the html file in default edge browser

Answer (score 0):

The `Live Preview` extension has just added (in Insiders Build now and Stable early February 2023) the ability to change the default browser that is opened (when you choose to open it in an external browser rather than as another tab within vscode).  See [Add option to choose default external browser](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-livepreview/commit/e763b37f8aa91c15ee6a95275777967f40abbe24).

The setting is

```
Live Preview: Custom External Browser
livePreview.customExternalBrowser
```

Options: Edge, Chrome, Firefox, none

`none` will use whatever you have set as your default browser in your operating system.  The new setting allows you to override that `default` setting with another browser for the purposes of the `Live Preview` extension opening an external browser, via the command:

```
Live Preview: Show Preview (External Browser)
```

Answer (score -1):

Ctrl + F1 will open the default browser. alternatively you can hit Ctrl + shift + P to open command window and select "View in Browser". The html code must be saved in a file (unsaved code on the editor - without extension, doesn't work)

Comment: What version of Visual Studio Code are you using? Those commands aren't working in my just-updated 1.8.1. Ctrl+F1 does nothing and I don't have a View in Browser option in the command palette. Maybe you have something beyond the default installed or extra tasks in your tasks.json?

Comment: I have the same version but I realized I installed an extension for it. It is: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qinjia.view-in-browser

Answer (score -1):

Recently came across this feature in one of the visual studio code tutorial in [www.lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com)

Press Ctrl + K followed by M, it will open the "Select Language Mode" ( or click on the right hand bottom corner that says HTML before that smiley ), type markdown and press enter

Now Press Ctrl + K followed by V, it will open your html in a near by tab.

Tadaaa !!!

Now emmet commands were not working in this mode in my html file, so I went back to the original state ( note - html tag tellisense were working perfectly )

To go to original state - Press Ctrl + K followed by M, select auto-detect. emmet commands started to work. If you are happy with html only viewer, then there is no need for you to come back to the original state.

Wonder why vscode is not having html viewer option by default, when it is able to dispaly the html file in the markdown mode.

Comment: The question is about how to view in a browser.

Answer (score -1):

probably most will be able to find a solution from the above answers but seeing as how none worked for me (`vscode v1.34`) i thought i'd share my experience. if at least one person finds it helpful then, cool not a wasted post, *amiirte*?

---

anyway, my solution (`windows`) is built a-top of @noontz's. his configuration may have been sufficient for older versions of `vscode` but not with `1.34` (at least, i couldn't get it working ..).

our configs are *nearly* identical save a single property -- that property being, the `group` property. i'm not sure why but without this, my task would not even appear in the command palette.

so. a working `tasks.json` for `windows` users running `vscode 1.34`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Chrome",
            "type": "process",
            "command": "chrome.exe",
            "windows": {
                "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
            },
            "args": [
                "${file}"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

note that the `problemMatcher` property is not required for this to work but without it an extra manual step is imposed on you. tried to read the docs on this property but i'm too thick to understand. hopefully someone will come about and school me but yeah, thanks in advance for that. all i know is -- include this property and `ctrl+shift+b` opens the current `html` file in a new `chrome` tab, hassle free.

---

easy.

Answer (score -1):

#### Open custom Chrome with URL from prompt

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Open Chrome",
      "type": "process",
      "windows": {
        "command": "${config:chrome.executable}"
      },
      "args": ["--user-data-dir=${config:chrome.profileDir}", "${input:url}"],
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "url",
      "description": "Which URL?",
      "default": "http://localhost:8080",
      "type": "promptString"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Open custom Chrome with active file

```
{
  "label": "Open active file in Chrome",
  "type": "process",
  "command": "chrome.exe",
  "windows": {
    "command": "${config:chrome.executable}"
  },
  "args": ["--user-data-dir=${config:chrome.profileDir}", "${file}"],
  "problemMatcher": []
},
```

#### Notes

- if necessary, replace `windows` property by other OS
- replace `${config:chrome.executable}` with your custom chrome location, e.g. `"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"`
- replace `${config:chrome.profileDir}` with your custome chrome profile directory, e.g.
  `"C:/My/Data/chrome/profile"` or leave it out
- You can keep the variables like above if you want. To do so, add following entries in `settings.json` - user or workspace - , adjust paths to your needs:

```
"chrome.executable": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe",
"chrome.profileDir": "C:/My/Data/chrome/profile"
```

- You could re-use these variables e.g. in `launch.json` for debugging purposes: `"runtimeExecutable": "${config:chrome.executable}"`

Answer (score -1):

Install '**Live Server**' extension for the VS Code editor.

Write click any where in your .html page which opened in VS Code.

Click the option '**Open with Live Server**' from the list. Then it will open with
your default browser.

Answer (score -2):

Start the local web server!

(Assuming you have an index.html file in your project folder).

In the same terminal window (command prompt in Windows) run this command:

npm start