# use Boost on VS Code

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-code

g++ can't find boost/regex.hpp using this task:

```
{
            "taskName": "C4B", // Compile for debug with boost
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g","${fileBasename}""-o","${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "type": "shell"
        },
```

I tried also using this arg: `"-IC:\\boost\\include\\boost-1_64\\boost"`

g++ is installed throug MinGW and i added the bin to PATH enviroment variable

I always used Visual Studio IDE...i'm new to command line stuff

This is how I include path on VS Code:

```
    "includePath": [
                    "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\5.3.0\\include\\c++",
                    "C:\\boost\\include\\boost-1_64\\boost"

                ],
    "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\5.3.0\\include\\c++",
                    "C:\\boost\\include\\boost-1_64\\boost"

                ],
```

Before this I included only `C:\\boost\\include`

And this is the error:

```
test1.cpp:1:27: fatal error: boost/regex.hpp: No such file or directory
```

compilation terminated.
How i can resolve this?

---

UPDATE 1:

So i included both include and lib folder:

```
"includePath": [
                "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\5.3.0\\include\\c++",
                "C:\\boost\\include",
                "C:\\boost\\lib"

            ],
```

and my compilation task is:

```
{
            "taskName": "C4B", // Compile for debug with boost
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g","${fileBasename}","-IC:\\boost\\include\\boost-1_64","-o","${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "type": "shell"
        }
```

now i have this output:

```
C:\Users\dj_al\AppData\Local\Temp\cctBnhDJ.o: In function `ZN5boost16re_detail_10640027cpp_regex_traits_char_layerIcEC2
ERKNS0_21cpp_regex_traits_baseIcEE':
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:370: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106400::c
pp_regex_traits_char_layer<char>::init()'
C:\Users\dj_al\AppData\Local\Temp\cctBnhDJ.o: In function `ZN5boost16re_detail_10640011raw_storage6extendEj':
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/regex_raw_buffer.hpp:131: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106400::r
aw_storage::resize(unsigned int)'
C:\Users\dj_al\AppData\Local\Temp\cctBnhDJ.o: In function `ZN5boost16re_detail_10640015save_state_initC1EPPNS0_11saved_
stateES4_':
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_non_recursive.hpp:107: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail
_106400::get_mem_block()'
C:\Users\dj_al\AppData\Local\Temp\cctBnhDJ.o: In function `ZN5boost16re_detail_10640015save_state_initD1Ev':
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_non_recursive.hpp:115: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail
_106400::put_mem_block(void*)'
C:\Users\dj_al\AppData\Local\Temp\cctBnhDJ.o: In function `ZN5boost16re_detail_10640012perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__norm
al_iteratorIPKcNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEESaINS_9sub_matchISC_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp
_regex_traitsIcEEEEE9match_impEv':
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_common.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106400
::verify_options(unsigned int, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
C:\Users\dj_al\AppData\Local\Temp\cctBnhDJ.o: In function `ZN5boost16re_detail_10640012perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__norm
al_iteratorIPKcNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEESaINS_9sub_matchISC_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp
_regex_traitsIcEEEEE18unwind_extra_blockEb':
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_non_recursive.hpp:1352: undefined reference to `boost::re_detai
l_106400::put_mem_block(void*)'
C:\Users\dj_al\AppData\Local\Temp\cctBnhDJ.o: In function `ZN5boost16re_detail_10640011raise_errorINS_20regex_traits_wr
apperINS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEEEvRKT_NS_15regex_constants10error_typeE':
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/pattern_except.hpp:75: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106400::raise_r
untime_error(std::runtime_error const&)'
C:\Users\dj_al\AppData\Local\Temp\cctBnhDJ.o: In function `ZN5boost16re_detail_10640012perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__norm
al_iteratorIPKcNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEESaINS_9sub_matchISC_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp
_regex_traitsIcEEEEE12extend_stackEv':
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_non_recursive.hpp:222: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail
_106400::get_mem_block()'
C:\Users\dj_al\AppData\Local\Temp\cctBnhDJ.o: In function `ZN5boost16re_detail_10640018basic_regex_parserIcNS_12regex_t
raitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE4failENS_15regex_constants10error_typeEiNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIc
ESaIcEEEi':
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_parser.hpp:237: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::rege
x_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::regex_constants:
:error_type, int)'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_parser.hpp:238: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::rais
e() const'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_parser.hpp:237: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~reg
ex_error()'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_parser.hpp:237: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~reg
ex_error()'
C:\Users\dj_al\AppData\Local\Temp\cctBnhDJ.o: In function `ZN5boost16re_detail_10640019basic_regex_creatorIcNS_12regex_
traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE16fixup_recursionsEPNS0_14re_syntax_baseE':
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:783: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::reg
ex_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::regex_constants
::error_type, int)'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:784: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::rai
se() const'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:783: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~re
gex_error()'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:872: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::reg
ex_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::regex_constants
::error_type, int)'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:873: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::rai
se() const'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:872: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~re
gex_error()'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:783: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~re
gex_error()'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:872: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~re
gex_error()'
C:\Users\dj_al\AppData\Local\Temp\cctBnhDJ.o: In function `ZN5boost16re_detail_10640019basic_regex_creatorIcNS_12regex_
traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE16create_startmapsEPNS0_14re_syntax_baseE':
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:938: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::reg
ex_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::regex_constants
::error_type, int)'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:939: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::rai
se() const'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:938: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~re
gex_error()'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:938: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~re
gex_error()'
C:\Users\dj_al\AppData\Local\Temp\cctBnhDJ.o: In function `ZN5boost16re_detail_10640019basic_regex_creatorIcNS_12regex_
traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE15create_startmapEPNS0_14re_syntax_baseEPhPjh':
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:1139: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::re
gex_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::regex_constant
s::error_type, int)'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:1140: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::ra
ise() const'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:1139: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~r
egex_error()'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:1139: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~r
egex_error()'
C:\Users\dj_al\AppData\Local\Temp\cctBnhDJ.o: In function `ZNK5boost16re_detail_10640031cpp_regex_traits_implementation
IcE12error_stringENS_15regex_constants10error_typeE':
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:447: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106400::g
et_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:449: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106400::g
et_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)'
C:\Users\dj_al\AppData\Local\Temp\cctBnhDJ.o: In function `ZN5boost16re_detail_10640019basic_regex_creatorIcNS_12regex_
traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE12insert_stateEiNS0_19syntax_element_typeEj':
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:320: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106400
::raw_storage::insert(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
C:\Users\dj_al\AppData\Local\Temp\cctBnhDJ.o: In function `ZN5boost12object_cacheINS_16re_detail_10640021cpp_regex_trai
ts_baseIcEENS1_31cpp_regex_traits_implementationIcEEE3getERKS3_j':
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/pending/object_cache.hpp:66: undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mutex
_lock::scoped_static_mutex_lock(boost::static_mutex&, bool)'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/pending/object_cache.hpp:66: undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mutex
_lock::~scoped_static_mutex_lock()'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/pending/object_cache.hpp:66: undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mutex
_lock::~scoped_static_mutex_lock()'
C:\Users\dj_al\AppData\Local\Temp\cctBnhDJ.o: In function `ZNK5boost16re_detail_10640031cpp_regex_traits_implementation
IcE18lookup_collatenameEPKcS4_':
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:680: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106400::l
ookup_default_collate_name(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
C:\Users\dj_al\AppData\Local\Temp\cctBnhDJ.o: In function `ZN5boost16re_detail_10640031cpp_regex_traits_implementationI
cE4initEv':
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:721: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106400::r
aise_runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:736: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106400::g
et_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)'
C:\Users\dj_al\AppData\Local\Temp\cctBnhDJ.o: In function `ZN5boost16cpp_regex_traitsIcE16get_catalog_nameEv':
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:1117: undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mute
x_lock::scoped_static_mutex_lock(boost::static_mutex&, bool)'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:1117: undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mute
x_lock::~scoped_static_mutex_lock()'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_64/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:1117: undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mute
x_lock::~scoped_static_mutex_lock()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Are you sure about `-I\\C:`? Shouldn't that be just `-IC:\boost\\include\\boost-1_64\\boost`?

Comment: i correct the path with -IC:\\boost\\include\\boost-1_64\\boost but the result is the same

Comment: `C:\boost\lib` should be in library paths, not include paths. You should also add the libraries to link with. From the compiler output it looks like the library for Boost.Regex is missing.

Comment: VS Code has only includePath and browse.path i don't know if there is something for linking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `C:\boost\include\boost-1_64` is where you installed Boost (i.e. unpacked the source package) then that is the path you should add to your include directories, not `C:\boost\include\boost-1_64\boost`. The trailing `boost` directory is present in `#include` directives in the code.

If you're using a graphical IDE I would expect it to automatically perform escaping the backslash ('\') characters as necessary when it saves the project. Otherwise you might have to escape them manually.

Comment: I'm not confident with this command line stuff. I installed boost in this way:

unpacked on Downloads folder and then run bootstrap gcc and b2 --prefix=C:\boost --toolset=gcc install

so i have include and libs folder in C:\boost

Comment: `b2 --prefix=C:\boost install` puts headers into `C:\boost\include` and built libraries into `C:\boost\lib`, so those are the paths you should add to your include and library paths.

Comment: Also, you can surely see where files are installed in the filesystem explorer.

Answer (score 3):

As [Andrey Semashev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4636534/andrey-semashev) said be sure to use the install location of Boost and not the unpacked source location. Standard if you haven't chosen a install prefix while installing Boost this would be C:\Boost on Windows.

For me in Visual Studio Code the only thing i needed to do is open the [task.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268034/where-is-the-tasks-json-file-in-vscode) of my project and at the following lines as followed:

"args":[
"-I",
"C:/Boost/include/boost-1_73"
]

This creates an compiler argument which includes the directory of boost. Then inside the file you should be able to include Boost as following example: #include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>.

Below the whole tasks.json file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\myProgram.exe",
                "-I",
                "C:/Boost/include/boost-1_73"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The `"-I", "C:/Boost/include/boost-1_73"` args in `taks.json` solves my question.