# Where is the Compile and Run Button?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm frustrated with VS Code. In Adobe Brackets, I can press the Live Display button, and it will open up my index.html file in chrome.

Regardless of what programming language you're using, you need to "compile" and run the code. Even if you write HTML, CSS and JS, you need to view it in the browser.

Where's the button to make that happen in VS Code? Why doesn't it have a "compile" button?

I've tried following the instructions from here: [How to view my HTML code in browser with Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039512/how-to-view-my-html-code-in-browser-with-visual-studio-code)

What happens is that Windows Explorer opens up or Chrome tells me it failed to load my html file.

Why do I need to configure task runners? A one-click button to compile and display code is a very important feature for a code editor. Can't Microsoft figure out a way to detect what code I'm working on and call the correct compiler to run it?

Does anyone have a guide to getting VS Code working for HTML/CSS/JS and for C#? VS Codes FAQ page for HTML doesn't have any information about loading HTML.

Comment: VS Code isn't what I would consider a good editor, but in it's defense, you should generally run web code through a local server rather than from the file system, which is a much more complicated task.

Comment: did you change the args to your html file? Try to give absolute path if it doesn't work.

Comment: Why not just use the ordinary command prompt? Much easier. More control.

Comment: I'm just learning programming. I need simple, working solutions. Brackets can do it. Can VS Code?

Comment: @Code_Steel: I haven't used Code very much but I have it installed. There is a "Toggle dev tools" in the HELP menu. Weird place for it. But it seems to be just tools for web development, not for C++ programming. Anyway when I want to use a light-weight editor I use Notepad++, because it has e.g. block editing. Doesn't look so fancy but is reliable and has lots of extensions.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is an utter crap, just uninstall it and don't waste time with it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming

Answer (score 6):

Right click in WorkSpace and select Run "anything" File in Terminal 
another way you can use "Code Runner" in the link below:
[Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)