# Cannot launch Chrome app for ASP.NET Core project

Tags: macos, google-chrome, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I would like to launch Chrome app when start debugging.
Looking on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31357118/2833802) SO answer and [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug) vscode-chrome-debug readme
I have tried to achieve this adding the following command into `launch.json`:

```
"osx": {
   "command": "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222"
},
```

on start in debug console log there is message like this:

```
Launching browser (/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome 
--remote-debugging-port=9222 http://localhost:5000)
```

but nothing happen (Chrome app not launch/new tab not open if Chrome already running).

On the other hand, if I run this command in terminal directly it works

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 http://localhost:5000
```