# Visual Code - preview by opening the browser using its GUI

Tags: html

is there any way how to preview HTML file by opening the browser automatically in its GUI? I mean like clicking some button there so it opens tab in browser? Going to my project's directory and opening index.html is just too weird.
Thanks.

Comment: do you ask about Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to view my HTML code in browser with Visual Studio Code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039512/how-to-view-my-html-code-in-browser-with-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

I think the code editor `brackets` has a built in preview

http://brackets.io/

the icon is the in the top right corner,

I think dreamweaver has something too

what about opening index.html is weird?