# Is there any way to quickly view a Visual Studio Code HTML page on a Mac in different browsers like in Sublime Text

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, text-editor

I learned how to open HTML files on a Mac in Chrome via Cmd + shift + b from the accepted answer here, but I miss being able to easily choose any browser like I can by right clicking in Sublime Text. [How to view my HTML code in browser with Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039512/how-to-view-my-html-code-in-browser-with-visual-studio-code/30043507#comment72136180_30043507)

Is there anyway to make shortcuts to do this in Visual Studio Code?

I'm stuck because I don't know why cmd + shift + b is the shortcut to open the HTML page in Chrome (I'm assuming it has something to do with "building" the app) so I don't know how I'd be able to make separate build commands / shortcuts for each browser.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can set desired keyboard shortcuts to tasks via the `key` property. Example:

```
{
"key": "ctrl+h",
"command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
"args": "build"
}
```

Additional details can be found here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_binding-keyboard-shortcuts-to-tasks

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to view HTML files in a different browser on Mac is to change my default browser (by clicking on the Apple menu and selecting System Preferences >> General >> Default web browser >> choose the browser you want) [select default browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmZHj.png), then in VSCode right clicking on the html.index file and selecting either "Open With Live Server" or "View In Browser"
[view in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqidU.png)