# How to change the default browser in visual studio code latest released？

Tags: html

As the title has said.The default browser is IE,but I want another browser to be used.How can I do for this?

Comment: visual studio code is not the same as visual studio.Thank you for  your answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio opens the default browser instead of Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79954/visual-studio-opens-the-default-browser-instead-of-internet-explorer)

Comment: you can find the solution [her](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039512/how-to-view-my-html-code-in-browser-with-visual-studio-code)
this solution used the tasks.json file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the default browser as chrome in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47519768/how-do-i-set-the-default-browser-as-chrome-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 3):

You can change Windows Default setting programs to your Browser.

Windows7 :

Controlpanel --> Programs-->set default programs

Comment: Chrome is my default browser, but VS code doesn't care. It still opens in Edge, which doesn't let me simply right click and inspect element and read console logs.

Comment: This answer is correct for changing the Windows default browser.

It does not answer the question of how to change the default browser within Visual Studio Code

Answer (score -1):

1. Install extension qinjia.view-in-browser.
2. Press F1, find parameter 'view-in-browser.customBrowser'.
3. Select your browser while editting.