# Visual Studio Code change browser

Tags: visual-studio-code, browser

I am following an react.js tutorial and i am using visual studio code for the IDE.
I want to change the default browser to chrome.
I tried doing this below but it doesn't recognize the command and i tried using view-in browser packages etc.
Press Ctrl+Shift+P to open the Command Palette. Type “ctr” and select the Configure Task Runner command to open tasks.json.
Can anyone suggest an easy way of doing this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the default browser as chrome in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47519768/how-do-i-set-the-default-browser-as-chrome-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
Chrome's settings >for me (Mac),  there is a Default browser "MAKE DEFAULT" button.