# How to change default browser with VS Code's "open with live server"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It defaults to my safari but would like to change it to chrome. I looked in preferences, but there doesn't seem to be an option for that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 69):

Go to **Files** > **Prefrences** > **Settings**

From Default User settings choose `LiveServer Config`

Inside it click on pen icon to the left on `liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser` select `chrome`.

Comment: Code > Preferences > Settings is correct. The first drop down is "Code" not "File", in VSCode.

Answer (score 24):

1. Go into settings. Shortcut: hold command then comma on mac.
2. In the top search bar search: liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser
3. You will see: Live Server > Settings: Custom Browser
4. In the drop down menu select whatever browser you want e.g. chrome or chrome:PrivateMode etc..

or

1. Open settings.json file
2. Type or copy and paste the following in the next line: "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome"
3. Make sure that there is a comma after the code in the previous line.

e.g.

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome"
```

Answer (score 13):

Thanks! to above answers. On Mac select VS and press [**command + ,**] or from menubar choose **code->Preferences->Settings**. It will open the Settings tab and enter **live server config** in search bar follow the steps given below

[image]

Answer (score 9):

This is how I did it on MacOS (you have to hit the gear, then select "Configure Extension Settings")

[image]

Comment: Nice tip. Just checked and it is the same on Windows :)

Answer (score 3):

I was also looking for this, while trying to change to Google Chrome Dev.

And discovered you can practically change to any browser you want, just type the name of the app on your settings.json

Example:

```
"liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "Google Chrome Dev"
```

Comment: Note that it also works with `"liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chromium",` on Linux, if Chromium is already started

Answer (score 2):

## How to customize your non-traditional browser in "liveServer"?

1. Go to `Files > Preferences > Settings` and search `.json` and click on `settings.json` file
2. or press **`SHIFT + CTRL + P`** and tab `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`
3. Write on JSON file

`"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine":` To set your any favorite browser (Eg: Chrome Canary, Firefox Nightly) using advance Command Line. (You can specify full path of your favorite custom browser).

- This setting will override `"CustomBrowser"` and `"ChromeDebuggingAttachment"` settings.
- Default Value is null
- Examples:

  - chrome --incognito --headless --remote-debugging-port=9222
  - C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe --private-window

Check out my [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs6uu.png) or see this [link on GitHub](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/blob/master/docs/settings.md) for more details.

> Note: Either use `"AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine"` or `"CustomBrowser"`. If
>   you use both, `"AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine"` has higher priority.

Answer (score 1):

If you had installed globally your live-server while using npm package, you can easily start your live-server on the browser of your choice by passing browser option on your launching command:

On your terminal type :`live-server --browser=BROWSER_NAME` 
Eg:
`live-server --browser=firefox,
live-server --browser=safari`

and some macbooks accepts 
    `live-server --browser='Google Chrome'` for google chrome while others 
    `live-server --browser=google-chrome`
NB:For mac `live-server --browser=chrome` will throw an error

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 2 steps:-
1) In `package.json` under `scripts` section create a key value as `"devserver": "live-server --browser=Chrome"`. 
2) In terminal run `npm run devserver`
This will open application in chrome.

Comment: this solution in working to open application by default on chrome terminal. But can we do some setting in IDE itself?

Comment: In old version of VS code task configuration works but for newer version you have to install Open in Browser extension from the marketplace. [For Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47519768/how-do-i-set-the-default-browser-as-chrome-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 1):

- Click windows+i
- Choose Apps
- Choose default apps
- Change (web browser ) to chrome (by change anyway)

Answer (score 1):

#### steps (change default browser for *open with Live Server*)

1. Go to [**File** > **Prefrences** > **Settings**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJb70.png)
2. Copy and paste `liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser` into the *Search settings* bar
3. Find the setting: *Live Server › Settings: Custom Browser*
4. Choose **chrome** or **chrome:PrivateMode** from the [dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdmsH.png)

Next time you **Open with Live Server** or **Go live**, the extension will automatically open with Chrome (no need to restart VSCode).

Answer (score 1):

Open live server in Google Chrome Canary [MacOS]

`"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "/Applications/Google Chrome Canary.app"`

Past this line in setting.json in place of `"liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "<-default browser->"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the live server extension https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server it has this setting:

> liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser:
>
> To change your system's default
>   browser. Default value is "Null" [String, not null]. (It will open
>   your system's default browser.) Available Options :  chrome
>   chrome:PrivateMode firefox firefox:PrivateMode microsoft-edge

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, via VS Code menu:

Code > Preferences > Settings > type `browser` in the Search settings box at the top

Answer (score 0):

open the visual studio and go to
`file - preferences - extension` - right-click over Live server setting icon - then choose

edit in setting JSON
then you will find that sentence

`"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": ""`

just put your browser name between the double quotes

Answer (score 0):

**liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser**:To change your system's default browser.

- Default value is null [String, not null]. (It will open your system's default browser.)
- Available Options :

  - Chrome
  - chrome:PrivateMode
  - firefox
  - firefox:PrivateMode
  - microsoft-edge
  - blisk

Not enough? need more? open an/a issue/pull request on github. For now, use `liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine` settings (see below).

- **`liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine`**:To set your any favorite browser (Eg: Chrome Canary, Firefox Nightly) using advance Command Line. (You can specify full path of your favorite custom browser).
- This setting will override CustomBrowser and ChromeDebuggingAttachment settings.
- Default Value is null
- **Examples**:
- `chrome --incognito --headless --remote-debugging-port=9222`
- `C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe --private-window //Remove --Private-windows for normal Window`
- **Note**: Either use AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine or CustomBrowser. If you use both, AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine has higher priority.