# VS Code keeps opening code in Chromium instead of Chrome

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome

I'm trying to open my live server in Chrome but it keeps defaulting to Chromium, no idea why or where it even pulls it from since I only have chrome installed.

Chromium was working at first but it doesn't seem to handle CSS-grid and I need that now.

Comment: The follow post looks like it might have the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49289233/how-to-change-default-browser-with-vs-codes-open-with-live-server

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. VS Code only has one option for Chrome, and I have it set, it just opens up in Chromium anyways.