# Launch in VSCODE from Chrome to Edge

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like ask on the basis of the code. Given that my launch does not require for me to choose a launch icon to launch my HTML files.
I have tried using answers from here on Stack Overflow but they still give me the same error.

So I am really confused non what I should do. it is really affecting me because I highly prefer Microsoft Edge than the use of Google Chrome. SO will any person help me this my problem and issue I will really appreciate.

Comment: settings > live server > custom browser > edge.... or manually 1. copy that link (something like this http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html) 2. open edge 2. paste it to the next browser

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49289233/how-to-change-default-browser-with-vs-codes-open-with-live-server