# How do I select a browser to use for VS Code Live Server?

Tags: visual-studio-code, liveserver

I just installed Live Server in VS Code but when I try to open (within VS Code and NOT in an external window) it always uses Simple Browser with doesn't allow me to open Dev Tools. How do I set Chrome or Firefox as an alternative to Simple Browser within VS Code?

No luck with .json files, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change default browser with VS Code's "open with live server"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49289233/how-to-change-default-browser-with-vs-codes-open-with-live-server)

Answer (score 0):

open VS Code -> setting -> live server config -> Custom Browser
You can choose your desired browser.
[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks. That opens the page in the browser of choice externally. I'm trying to add either Chrome or Firefox within VS Code instead of having pages open in Simple Browser. Any suggestions on how to accomplish that?