# How can I reset the default browser setting in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The first time I right-clicked an html file in a workspace, vscode asked me which browser I want to use to preview the file. How can I bring that dialog back? I can't find it in any settings files, and I don't seem to have tasks.json or launch.json files. Where was this setting saved, and how do I revert that change?

[How do I set the default browser as chrome in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47519768) and several other questions dating back several years don't address this question. It's possible those questions are just dated, referencing config files that are no longer relevant.

I'm running vscode 1.37.1 downloaded yesterday.
Where is this setting saved, and how do I revert it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the default browser as chrome in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47519768/how-do-i-set-the-default-browser-as-chrome-in-visual-studio-code)