# Set Chromium as default browser in VS 2019 Community

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, default, chromium

I'd like to set [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/) as the default browser to debug ASP.NET Core applications. Unfortunately, it is not listed in the available browsers:

[image]

`Select Web Browsers...` option opens a dialog in which same browsers are listed but not sign of Chromium whatsoever:

[image]

In fact it repeats the information in the menu, nothing more. No way to search installed apps or something...

Looks like Chromium is not a "first class citizen" in VS2019!

So, my question is: **Does anybody know how to make Chromium the default browser when debugging ASP.NET Core MVC applications?**

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Please, let's respect each other... Do not post answers like "start debugging with another browser then switch to Chromium."

Comment: You can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47519768/how-do-i-set-the-default-browser-as-chrome-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 0):

OK, the comment by [@Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13170277/ahmed-abdallah) pours some light, only it remains a bit dimmed. Tasks.json didn't help in finding Chromium in the browser list.

The explanation found here didn't solve the problem either: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customize-build-and-debug-tasks-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019.

So, the answer now... 
Despite I didn't want to change the default browser (I love my Opera!), **making Chromium the default browser solved this small but boring issue** - Chromium appeared in the browser list and I was able to launch it.