# How to open URL in chrome in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple AI. I've added some functions. But every time when I try to open links it automatically opens in INTERNET EXPLORER. I wanna open the URL in google chrome. 
So what I've to do? Please help me.

[Here's the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6P1z.png)

Comment: Just change your default browser, It should open in chrome. Also take a look at this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47519768/how-do-i-set-the-default-browser-as-chrome-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Could you send the source code, please?

Comment: It would be helpful if you copy-paste the error as formatted text instead of a link, as it seems people are not even aware you are in fact using `webbrowser`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `webbrowser`:

```
import webbrowser

url = 'http://docs.python.org/'

# MacOS
chrome_path = 'open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app %s'

# Windows
chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'

# Linux
chrome_path = '/usr/bin/google-chrome %s'

webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Chrome as your default browser.

Answer (score 0):

#import the given web browser and copy the link

import webbrowser as urlopen

urlopen.open('http://example.com')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).