# VSCode ASP.Net Core 6.0 launch chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, browser, vscode-debugger

I am using the latest version of VS Code. I have the following `launch.json`:

```
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "ApplicationStarted",
                "uriFormat": "https://localhost:%s",
            },
```

I don't have specific output string when application starts. Should I put one? Where should I put it?

Reference: [How do I set the default browser as chrome in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47519768/how-do-i-set-the-default-browser-as-chrome-in-visual-studio-code)

Using the suggest by @Deepak-MSFT results in the following exception:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `"type": "pwa-chrome",` under configurations in `launch.json` file.

Example:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "pwa-chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch my cool app",
      "url": "http://localhost:8000"
    }
  ]
}
```

Reference: [Launching browsers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging#_launching-browsers)

See whether it helps to launch the Google Chrome browser.

Comment: It launches the browser but there is exception that stops the application debugging session.

Comment: Using this approach will hide this error https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/41417 ?

Comment: The error you are seeing is a different issue. Based on the exception, it looks like some DLL or library is missing and this is the reason you are getting this exception. It has nothing to do with the above suggestion. So above suggestion will not help you to hide the error but it could help you to launch the project in the Google Chrome browser.

Comment: Don't think so. I see exception in the javascript but not this .Net core clr exception.

Comment: I would like to confirm with you if you remove `"type": "pwa-chrome","request": "launch",` from `launch.json` file then are you able to run your project successfully without any error? Could you please share the error screenshot? I am not getting idea where exactly you are getting it.

Comment: I get the breakpoint at the CLR exception https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/41417 without the change suggested by you. With your changes, I get different exception at some javascript code.

Comment: If possible could you please share that exception that you are getting in the Javascript code?

Comment: Added in my post