# Visual Studio Code 1.17.1 Open in Browser without opening terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

Looks like an old question, but no proper answers found.
I've looked at [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#vscode) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039512/how-to-view-my-html-code-in-browser-with-visual-studio-code).
Right now, I can open Chrome by doing this:

**task.json:**

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo Hello"
        },
        {
            "taskName": "Open in Chrome",
            // "type": "process",
            "windows": {
                "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
            },
            "args": ["${file}"],
        }
    ]
}
```

**keybindings.json:**

```
[{
        "key": "ctrl+alt+g",
        "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
        "args": "Open in Chrome"
 },]
```

Note that I don't even need `type: process` to make it run and can only run it using my own key binding. If I use ctrl+shift+B (Windows), it'll allow one task only.

However, every time I run the task, the terminal is also opened with: `Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.` which is repetitive and not really helpful for front-end work.

Is there a way to turn that off?

I've tried adding:

```
"presentation": {
                "reveal": "never" //same with "silent"
            }
```

to the task in task.json but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try either "panel": "shared" or "panel": "dedicated" to see if it helps with that message?  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_output-behavior

Comment: @Mark thanks for your suggestions.
panel: shared still opens the terminal like mentioned above.
panel: dedicated doesn't show the page, it shows the task.json file on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to close question:
The easiest way is to use an extension like this one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=techer.open-in-browser