# How can I make VSCode render my HTML file on firefox whenever I run it

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, firefox

This is probably a stupid question, but I am new to coding. How can I make VSCode open Firefox display my HTML whenever I press run? Keep in mind that I am on Ubuntu.

Comment: Please give more information about what you want to run and how. For example, and you developing a React or Vue app with Vite?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48721885/19860022)

Comment: I have a simple HTML site and I want to view it on Firefox whenever click run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file in your workspace `.vscode/launch.json` with the following contents:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Open in Firefox",
            "command": "firefox ${file}; exit",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "node-terminal"
        },
    ]
}
```

Afterwards the run button should look like this and open your currently open file in Firefox:

[image]