# Visual Code Code language not supported or defined

Tags: visual-studio-code

So Installed Visual Code and a bunch of extensions but i cannot run my html files... have no idea how to fix this!

I had visual code installed previously and it was working just fine till i noticed i was´nt been able to find my last html projects files, so i deleted visual code and installed it again, when i opened the new visual code, my new issue is that whenever i try to run my html files, visual code displays this:"Code language not supported or defined."

Comment: what do you mean by "run"? It's markup. What extension did you install that you think "runs" it? Live Server?

Comment: hey thanks for reaching out, what i mean by "Run" is to be able to see what´s my code programing by clicking that "play" button? i´m sorry if i´m not explaining myself the proper way or accurate.

Comment: duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/q/30039512/11107541 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to view an HTML file in the browser with Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039512/how-to-view-an-html-file-in-the-browser-with-visual-studio-code)